SOQL CRMA BINDING error
I have this query and it functions correctly until i select a filter value. Been trying to fix it and don't understand what could be the error or if there is limitation for SOQL and CRMA functionality.

SELECT ID, Account__r.End_Date__c, SUM(A__c), SUM(Shop__r.B__c), COUNT(Shop__r.Id), Account__r.ABC__r.Name FROM XYZ__c WHERE (Shop__r.Status__c IN ('Active', 'Cancelled', 'New', NULL) OR Name IN ('{{column(Name_1.selection, ["Name"]).asObject()}}')) OR (Account__r.ABC__r.Name IN ('{{column(lens_2.selection, ["Account__r.ABC__r.Name "]).asObject()}}')) GROUP BY ID, Account__r.End_Date__c, Account__r.ABC__r.Name

The List selector is on User Object
and error that shows up is The binding 'column(lens_2.selection, ["Account__r.ABC__r.Name "]).asObject()' contains an error: The column name 'Account__r.ABC__r.Name' doesn't exist in the data.
What could be the error here? should the object that we are querying should have the Values that are getting filter on and related object can't be used a filter on dashboard?
